# What are the effects of the alphabet size on construct algorithms for suffix trees?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, strings, efficiency, suffix-trees

For what size alphabet does it take longer to construct [a suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) - for a really small alphabet size (because it has to go deep into the tree) or for a large alphabet size? Or is it dependent on the algorithm you use? If it is dependent, how does the alphabet size affect [Ukkonen's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm)?

Answer (score 6):

A larger alphabet is usually a drawback. However there are algorithms that can deal with this as long as the alphabet size is $n^{O(1)}$.

Ukkonen's algorithm runs only in $O(n)$ if the alphabet size is a constant but it is $O(n \log n)$ without this assumption. However, there are alternatives. You can compute the [suffix-array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) of a text in linear time with the [DC-3 Algorithm](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/documents/jacm05-revised.pdf). This is a super-cool fancy algorithm that can be implemented in 50 lines of readable C++ code - one of my all-time favorites. If you can compare two characters in constant time and the alphabet size is $n^{O(1)}$, then the DC3 algorithm runs in $O(n)$ time.

Notice that you can get the suffix tree out of the suffix array in $O(n)$ time, when you have the [LCP-array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array). Basically, you compute the Cartesian tree of the LCP-array and use the suffix-array to label the nodes. The LCP-array can be also computed with the DC3-algorithm.

Comment: +1 for answering the question and also mentioning suffix arrays, and the super-cool fancy algorithm!